# Docker run inside container, on mounted host daemon - mounting host drive on sibling container sometimes works

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, docker-compose

I have a host Windows machine which runs a container 1. This container mounts the host Docker daemon and a plain directory; docker compose is running in Git Bash:

```
      - ~/.aws:/root/.aws:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /f/controller/offshore:/app/offshore:rw
```

Container 1 runs container 2 using the host's daemon and `docker run -v /f/controller/offshore:/host`, so that some self contained processing can happen on files put into the `/app/offshore` mount. This is working correctly with the above mounting.

If I change `/f/controller/offshore` to `~/offshore` then I find that container 2 cannot see the files created by container 1 (the files are present if I navigate in the host filesystem). If I run myself on the host machine, the command which container 1 ran, then container 2 launches and successfully sees the files.

I thought this might be some permissions thing with the `~` mapping to `C:/Documents...` however when running this all in PowerShell without docker compose (ie running container 1 with `docker run -v F:\offshore:/app/offshore`) then the same problem appears.

The files are all temporary so I haven't created a separate volume, but perhaps I should? Does anyone know the reason why container 2 cannot see container 1's files? Or why it can sometimes? What is the optimum method to create a folder in container 1 which can be read/written in container 2, using the host daemon?